# IPv6 address validation and canonicalization

Tags: java, javascript, c++, python, ipv6

What libs have you used for that?  How compatible are they with one another?  Or did you write your own parsing routine?

I'm particularly interested in mutually-compatible implementations for Java, C++, Python, and JavaScript, which support:

- zero compression ("`::`")
- IPv4-mapped addresses ("`::ffff:123.45.67.89`")
- canonicalization (including to the short form, for human readability)
- CIDR-style netmasks (like "`/64`" at the end)

Comment: Please look at the `ip6` npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On POSIX systems you can use `inet_pton` and `inet_ntop` in combination to do canonicalization.  You will still have to do your own CIDR parsing.  Fortunately, I believe the only valid CIDR syntax for IPv6 is the /number_of_bits notation, so that's fairly easy.

The other issue you will run into is the lack of support for interface specifications.  For link-local addresses, you will see things like `%eth0` on the end to specify what link they are local too.  `getaddrinfo` will parse that but `inet_pton` won't.

One strategy you could go for is using `getaddrinfo` to parse and `inet_ntop` to canonicalize.

`getaddrinfo` is available for Windows.  `inet_pton` and `inet_ntop` aren't.  Fortunately, it isn't too hard to write code to produce a canonical form IPv6 address.  It will require two passes though because the rule for 0 compression is the biggest string of 0s that occurs first.  Also IPv4 form (i.e. `::127.0.0.1`) is only used for `::IPv4` or `::ffff:IPv4`.

I have no Windows machine to test with, but from the documentation it appears that Python on Windows supports `inet_pton` and `inet_ntop` in its socket module.

Writing your own routine for producing a canonical form might not be a bad idea, since even if your canonical form isn't the same as everybody else's, as long as it's valid other people can parse it.  But I would under no circumstances write a routine of your own to **parse** IPv6 addresses.

My advice above is good for Python, C, and C++.  I know little or nothing about how to solve this problem in Java or Javascript.

**EDIT**: I have been examining getaddrinfo and its counterpart, getnameinfo.  These are in almost all ways better than `inet_pton` and `inet_ntop`.  They are thread safe, and you can pass them options (`AI_NUMERICHOST` in `getaddrinfo`'s case, and `NI_NUMERCHOST` in `getnameinfo`'s case) to keep them from doing any kind of DNS queries.  Their interface is a little complex and reminds me of an ugly Windows interface in some respects, but it's fairly easy to figure out what options to pass to get what you want.  I heartily recommend them both.

Comment: I would like to comment that after playing with getaddrinfo myself, the OSX 10.4 and glibc-2.10.1 versions both have interesting bugs.  The OSX version has much worse bugs.

Comment: Windows does support inet_pton and inet_ntop for Vista and later (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc805843%28VS.85%29.aspx). However, Python 2.6 and 3.0 does not (docs indicate Availability Unix).

Comment: Watch out for speed in Windows. For some reason the Windows inet_pton and inet_ntop are horribly horribly slow. Or they were in my experience on Vista and Server 2008.

Comment: @Omnifarious, you wrote, "_But I would under no circumstances write a routine of your own to parse IPv6 addresses._" I did exactly that that fairly easily using RegEx, and it accepts all legal forms of IPv6 addressing (compressed, uncompressed, hybrid compressed, hybrid uncompressed, and upper or lower case versions of each, with or without the `/<mask length>`). The reverse routine will return the RFC 5259 "official" canonical representation of IPv6 addresses, including hybrid for `/96` addresses.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, You could use

```
InetAddress.getByName(IP)
```

and then check for exceptions thrown by this for validating IPv6 addresses

You could also use Sun Propreitary API if thats oK to you. THis will not perform a DNS lookup. ( They might change it/remove it without notice since its their propreitary API.This is a warning that will come when compiling a code using this )

```
boolean sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.isIPv6LiteralAddress(String IP)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
Unfortunately that method does a DNS lookup before throwing the exception.

Comment: Okie.. I looked into source code of InetAddress. Its using sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil class. Its a sun propreietary API. But if that's okie to you, you could use it. Use the static method isIPv6LiteralAddress(String IP). It returns true or false

Comment: IPAddressUtil works great.  I guess I can cope with canonicalization too, via textToNumericFormatV*(String) and some custom formatting back to text.
+1 and I wish I could accept more than one answer.

Comment: Wow. Glad i could help! :) No prob at all!

Comment: You can use Guava's InetAddresses to avoid the lookup

Answer (score 5):

In Java, the Guava library has utility functions for validating IPv6 (and IPv4) in the com.google.common.net.InetAddresses class.  http://goo.gl/RucRU

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [javascript-ipv6](https://github.com/beaugunderson/javascript-ipv6) for this very purpose. It currently powers [v6decode.com](http://www.v6decode.com/).

Here's a short example of the API:

```
var address = new v6.Address("::ffff:7b2d:4359/64");

if (address.isValid()) {
   // Do something if the address is valid
}

console.log(address.correctForm());         // "::ffff:7b2d:4359"
console.log(address.canonicalForm());       // "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:7b2d:4359"
console.log(address.v4Form());              // "::ffff:123.45.67.89"
console.log(address.subnetMask);            // "64"
console.log(address.possibleAddresses(96)); // "4,294,967,296"
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a regular expression when os support may not be available - RE is available in most languages, including C/C++/Java/Python/Perl/bash/....  The following python code builds the RE at startup, the resulting RE source is a humdinger - but once compiled by the re engine is as fast as native code.

```
PAT_IP4 = r'\.'.join([r'(?:\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])']*4)
RE_IP4 = re.compile(PAT_IP4+'$')
RE_IP6 = re.compile(                 '(?:%(hex4)s:){6}%(ls32)s$'
               '|::(?:%(hex4)s:){5}%(ls32)s$'
              '|(?:%(hex4)s)?::(?:%(hex4)s:){4}%(ls32)s$'
'|(?:(?:%(hex4)s:){0,1}%(hex4)s)?::(?:%(hex4)s:){3}%(ls32)s$'
'|(?:(?:%(hex4)s:){0,2}%(hex4)s)?::(?:%(hex4)s:){2}%(ls32)s$'
'|(?:(?:%(hex4)s:){0,3}%(hex4)s)?::%(hex4)s:%(ls32)s$'
'|(?:(?:%(hex4)s:){0,4}%(hex4)s)?::%(ls32)s$'
'|(?:(?:%(hex4)s:){0,5}%(hex4)s)?::%(hex4)s$'
'|(?:(?:%(hex4)s:){0,6}%(hex4)s)?::$'
  % {
'ls32': r'(?:[0-9a-f]{1,4}:[0-9a-f]{1,4}|%s)'%PAT_IP4,
'hex4': r'[0-9a-f]{1,4}'
}, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you should use `getaddrinfo()` on systems that have it, i.e. Linux and POSIX places. There should be no need to write your own low-level parser.

Windows [also provides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28VS.85%29.aspx) `getaddrinfo()`, on XP and later.

Comment: I don't think getaddrinfo supports parsing subnet bit-slicing notation.  It also doesn't support canonicalization.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, the best solution might be IPy (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPy/0.51)

Answer (score 0):

getaddrinfo already returns the shortest textual form, so if you have the longer form you can canonicalize by running through getaddrinfo again.  Example Python,

```
import sys, socket;
result = socket.getaddrinfo('0:0::0:1', None);
print "family:%i socktype:%i proto:%i canonname:%s sockaddr:%s"%result[0];
```

Outputs the following,

```
family:10 socktype:1 proto:6 canonname: sockaddr:('::1', 0, 0, 0)
```

IPv6 CIDR blocks don't appear to be well documented or defined so I wrote my own [inet6_network implementation](http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/inet_network.c) to handle that (C99).

Answer (score 0):

i simply went through adhoc approach to check the validity of IPV4 and IPV6 both addressing scheme:here is my code ... corrections are always welcome in my code. and pardon me if my solution is wrong.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;
bool check6(string s)
{
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
       if((s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9') && (s[i] < 'a' || s[i]> 'f') && 
           (s[i] < 'A' || s[i] > 'F'))                       
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}
   bool check4(string s)
   {
      for(int i=0; i< s.length(); i++)
      {
       if(!(s[i]>= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
          return false;
      }
     stringstream ss(s);
      int e;
      ss >> e;
     if( e < 0 || e > 255 )
      return false;
     else
      return true;
   }

int main()
{
  string s;
  cin>>s;
  vector<string> v;
  int i=0;
  int d=0;
  if((s.find(":")!=std::string::npos || 
         s.find("::")!=std::string::npos)&&  
     s.find(".")==std::string::npos)     
   {
      int x=0;
      while(i< s.length())
      {
          string s1 ="";
          while(i< s.length() && s[i]!= ':')
          {
             s1+= s[i];
             i++;
          }
         if(s1!="")
         v.push_back(s1);
         if((i+1)< s.length() && s[i]==':' && s[i+1]==':')
            x++;
         i++;
         if(i< s.length())
         d++;
     }
      if(x > 1 || d > 7 || v.size() > 8 || (x==1 && d >6))
      {
         cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;
         return 0;
      }
      else if(d > 2 && v.size() ==0)
      {

         cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;
         return 0;
      }
      else
      {
         for(int i=0;i< v.size();i++)
         {
             if((v[i]).length() > 4)
             {
                    cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;
                 return 0;
              }
             else
             {
                if(!check6(v[i]))
                {

                    cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;
                    return 0;
                }
            }
         }
         cout<<"Valid Ipv6"<<endl;
          return 0;
      }
   }
else if(s.find(":")==std::string::npos && s.find(".")!=std::string::npos)
{
    while(i< s.length())
    {
        string s1="";
        while( i< s.length() && s[i]!='.')
        {
            s1+=s[i];
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        if(i< s.length())
        d++;
        v.push_back(s1);
    }
    if(d > 4 || v.size()> 4)
    {
        cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
        {
            if((v[i]).length() > 3)
            {
                cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            if(!check4(v[i]))
            {
                cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }   
    }
    cout<<"Valid Ipv4"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

        cout<<"Not Valid"<<endl;

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

It's too bad Python 3.1 lost the ipaddr lib.

It's still available as a third-party library: [py-ipaddr](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) available on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr).

### Compression

```
>>> ipaddr.IPv6Address('0:0::0:1').compressed
'::1'
```

### IPv4 mapping

```
>>> ipaddr.IPv6Address('::ffff:123.45.67.89').ipv4_mapped
IPv4Address('123.45.67.89')
```

### CIDR

```
>>> ipaddr.IPv6Network('::ffff:123.45.67.89/128')
IPv6Network('::ffff:7b2d:4359/128')
```

Answer (score -1):

For C#, I would recommend the use of IPNetwork Library https://github.com/lduchosal/ipnetwork. 
As of version 2, it supports IPv4 and IPv6 as well.

**IPv6**

```
  IPNetwork ipnetwork = IPNetwork.Parse("2001:0db8::/64");

  Console.WriteLine("Network : {0}", ipnetwork.Network);
  Console.WriteLine("Netmask : {0}", ipnetwork.Netmask);
  Console.WriteLine("Broadcast : {0}", ipnetwork.Broadcast);
  Console.WriteLine("FirstUsable : {0}", ipnetwork.FirstUsable);
  Console.WriteLine("LastUsable : {0}", ipnetwork.LastUsable);
  Console.WriteLine("Usable : {0}", ipnetwork.Usable);
  Console.WriteLine("Cidr : {0}", ipnetwork.Cidr);
```

Output

```
Network : 2001:db8::
Netmask : ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
Broadcast : 
FirstUsable : 2001:db8::
LastUsable : 2001:db8::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
Usable : 18446744073709551616
Cidr : 64
```

Have fun !

Comment: The output for first and last usable addresses is incorrect. IPv6, unlike IPv4, can use all the addresses in a subnet. A standard IPv6 subnet is /64 (a few special cases use other mask lengths), and the usable addresses are from `<subnet>::` to `<subnet>:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`. There is no reservation for the subnet (`<subnet>::`), and IPv6 doesn't have the concept of broadcast, so no broadcast address exists at `<subnet>:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`.

Comment: Thanks Ron for pointing this out.