# Very slow execution of document listener before a non alpha-numeric character

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

I have the following code.

```
JTextField addField = new JTextField();
IPChecker ipCheckLive = new IPChecker();
...

addField.setToolTipText("Enter IP");
sortPanel.add(addField,"growx, width 75:100:, height 20!, span 3");
doc = addField.getDocument();
doc.addDocumentListener(ipCheckLive);

...

private int ipInt() {
    try {
        String s = addField.getText();
        if(!s.equals("")){
            System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName(s));
            if(InetAddress.getByName(s) instanceof Inet4Address) {
                return 1;
            } else if(InetAddress.getByName(s) instanceof Inet6Address) {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException badAddress) {

    }
    return 0;
};

private class IPChecker implements DocumentListener {
    int ipType; //int ipType = ipInt(); => Gets value when DL declared so wouldn't update when char entered obvisouly
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ipType = ipInt();

        long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);

        if(ipType==1||ipType==-1) {
            addField.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ipType = ipInt();

        long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);

        if(ipType==1||ipType==-1) {
            addField.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ipType = ipInt();

        long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(totalTime);

        if(ipType==1||ipType==-1) {
            addField.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border"));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the code and enter a letter into the `addField` text box it can take as longer than 2.5 seconds to enter make the letter visible. However one a non alpha-numerical character is entered such as `(`, `)`, `:` and `!` the time taken to make the following entries in the text box visible are between 0 and 2 milliseconds.

Would someone be able to help me fix this please.

**Example**

**Input** :

```
 ffff:ffff
```

**Output** :

```
2253  // From the 'f'
2250  // From the 'f'
2251  // From the 'f'
2256  // From the 'f'
0     // From the ':'
0     // From the 'f'
0     // From the 'f'
0     // From the 'f'
0     // From the 'f'
```

*Time in milliseconds*

Comment: Are you seeing the time you need to resolve the dns-name "a"? Or what exactly does the function `InetAddress.getByName(s)` do. Even if you enter non-sense, it'll still fire a request, maybe. Also, you can cut the execution time in `ipInt()` to one-third of the original. Save the output of `InetAddress.getByName(s)` in a variable, no need to call the same function three times with the same argument. Also do the same thing for `if(ipInt()==1||ipInt()==-1)`, just do `int ipType = ipInt()`, then do the `if`-Check on that variable.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks. Your suggestion fixed it

Comment: Oh yes, ofcourse. The moment you enter a `!` it **cannot be a valid dns name anymore**. Therefore you immediatly jump into the `except` block, because the function cannot resolve the DNS name as it sees the name has invalid character. After that, it doesn't matter what you type, with the `!` being in there, no DNS-resolve is done. For possible optimiziation, see comment above.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt There is just one problem, which I just noticed. The `ipType` does not update unless it is in one of the three main voids in a document listener and then the speeds go back up.

Comment: Also when the character `:` is entered into the field it stops it going slow however it could still be a valid IP so it does not go to the catch block

Comment: You're right, `fe80::bc94:b0ed:c37f:9ed6%4` e.g. is a valid IPv6 address, but the function `InetAddress.getByName(String s)` is designed to "Determines the IP address of a host, given the host's name." (http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html ) (i.e. give you an IP address to the given name "www.google.com"). And in domain-names, no `:` is allowed. (In URLs it is, e.g. `www.google.de:80`), so the function is right to deny the request to resolve the name. What do you mean by "the variable doesn't get updated? Can you update your post with your current code?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I edited the code but it produces very similar times

Comment: You still haven't implemented the optimization inside `ipInt()` it's still 3-times slower than it should, I meant to do something like http://pastebin.com/TJCMGD4S . Also, the behavior for the `ipType` variable is normal, a change to this variable is only done when the content of the textfield changes (i.e. `changedUpdate()`, `insertUpdate()` or `removeUpdate()` fires), and that's also the only times when the variable should be updated. Are you sure these events fire seperatly from each other? (`changedUpdate()` and `insertUpdate()` e.g. don't get called at the same time / after each other?)

Comment: Sorry for extended commenting here, but I think I know what the problem is: You're using the wrong function. Guessing from the `Enter IP`, I think you want to check wether an entered IP adress string is IPv4 or IPv6? But at the moment you're DNS-resolving a website-name entered inside the textbox.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Okay I implemented your version and checked only one event fired at a time, and it is. It didn't make much difference at all unfortunately. I am trying to verify the type of IP address. I didn't realise I was DNS-resolving a website-name. What method would you suggest I use?

Comment: Most interestingly "If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked." (in `getByName()` above). But for the cases with an invalid IP, for "a" e.g. it'll still try to resolve it as a websitename. I've found library here (http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html#forString%28java.lang.String%29) that does it without a dns-lookup. But your method above is still *correct* (correctly distinguishes IPv4 adresses from v6 ones). For a different approach see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6936326/5296568

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thank you for all your help

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I found the way to bypass the DNS lookup with the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/net/util/IPAddressUtil.java?av=f)